# Return array of IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi
How can I return an array from a database call.

in this format: `["141", "138", "123", "128", "137", "139"]`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In Rails 4: (ht [@ri4a](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612392/ri4a))

```
User.ids # integer array
User.ids.map(&:to_s) # string array
```

In Rails 3/4:

```
User.pluck(:id) # integer array
User.pluck(:id).map(&:to_s) # string array
```

#### Old answer

If you want to go directly to the DB:

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values("select id from users")
["1", "2", "5", "6", "7", "8", "3", "10", "11", "9"]
```

If you already have a model:

```
User.all(:select => :id).collect(&:id)
```

First approach is faster than the 2nd as it does not incur the cost of constructing model instances.

Comment: This gives me [141, 138, 123, 128, 137, 139]

Comment: I need the "" around the numbers like this: ["141", "138", "123", "128", "137", "139"]

Comment: Try replacing `collect(&:id)` with `collect{|u|u.id.to_s}`

Answer (score 16):

If you have a `has_many`, then on the `has_many` side you can get the IDs for associated objects like this:

```
def User
  has_many :tasks
end

def Task
  belongs_to :user
end

ids = User.find(1).task_ids
```

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
ClassName.all.collect { |obj| obj.id }
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: No, this was an answer, and is very similar to the accepted answer. I don't know what gives you the impression that this is a comment.

Comment: It should be: `ClassName.pluck(:id)` or `ClassName.all.collect(&:id)`

Comment: I agree @Justin. Looking back years later, my answer was a n00b response and probably doesn't deserve the 3 votes it has :)

Answer (score 3):

If you use Model, there are new method - pluck. Comment.pluck(:id) #[1,2,3...]